# SQL JOIN or GROUP BY variant?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

**I have a table named "articulos_precios" like this:**

```
 articulo_id  precio  precio_empresa_id
 ----------- -------- -----------------
      1         10          11
      2         15          12
      1         20          13
      3         45          13
      2         10          13
      3         40          11
      1         25          12
      2         10          11
      3         40          12
```

**I need obtain something like this:**

```
 articulo_id  precio1  precio2   precio3
 ----------- -------- --------- ---------
      1         10       25         20
      2         10       15         10     
      3         40       40         45
```

where:

**precio1** is the price for precio_empresa_id:11,

**precio2** is the price for precio_empresa_id:12

**precio3** is the price for precio_empresa_id:13

I have try with this query:

```
select M.articulo_id,M.precio1,M.precio2,U.precio3 from
(select M.articulo_id,M.precio1,M.precio2 from
  (select Z.articulo_id,Z.precio as precio1 from precios_articulos Z where Z.precio_empresa_id=42) W full join
  (select Y.articulo_id,Y.precio as precio2 from precios_articulos Y where Y.precio_empresa_id=43) V
on W.articulo_id=V.articulo_id) M full join
  (select X.articulo_id,X.precio as precio3 from precios_articulos X where X.precio_empresa_id=42) U
on M.articulo_id=U.articulo_id;
```

but it have bery low performance. **Its possible to do it with some variant of Group By??** or somebody know how to do it?

---

This question has ben marqued as duplicate respect to: [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table), 
The main difference is that in this example the occurrences are not counted, but rather the contents of the table are grouped and restructured. Regards @Barmar

Comment: I think you are looking for `PIVOT`.

Comment: this is called a pivot.  mySQL doesn't support pivot but it can be emulated using case and max.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application level code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentation should be handled at the presentation layer.  However, if you must.... you can accomplish it this way:

```
SELECT articulo_id
     , max(case when precio_empresa_ID = 11 then precio end) as Precio1
     , max(case when precio_empresa_ID = 12 then precio end) as Precio2
     , max(case when precio_empresa_ID = 13 then precio end) as Precio3
FROM articulos_precios
GROUP BY articulo_id
```

Note: if you need additional precio_empresa_ID  you have to add additional case and max statements.

This can be accomplished using dynamic SQL if needed;but this gives the provides the general construct.

Alternatively instead of using max you could use a sum or count if your data has multiple occurrences and you need to sum / counting them instead of just displaying values.

```
SELECT articulo_id
     , sum(case when precio_empresa_ID = 11 then coalesce(precio,0) end) as Precio1
     , sum(case when precio_empresa_ID = 12 then coalesce(precio,0)end) as Precio2
     , sum(case when precio_empresa_ID = 13 then coalesce(precio,0)end) as Precio3
FROM articulos_precios
GROUP BY articulo_id
```

Comment: Wow!, its amazing, just i need. Tankyou Very Much!!.